# QGIS - Python to Add folder location to Browser - Favorites

Tags: qgis, pyqgis, qgis-browser

I am struggling to get something to work, which would seem to be an easy thing to do, but cannot quite make my understanding of the python docs work in practice.

What I would like to do, is run some python to add some folders to the favorites area in the browser within QGIS. This is to get round an environemental constraint of not being able to save a profile i.e. quickly add a python script to setup the favorites each time log on.

This is what I have tried thus far:

```
url = "U:\Tyres"
qgis.gui.QgsBrowserDockWidget(addFavoriteDirectory, uri)
```

...

> Traceback (most recent call last):   File
>   "C:\OSGEO4~1\apps\Python37\lib\code.py", line 90, in runcode
>       exec(code, self.locals)   File "", line 1, in    File "", line 3, in  NameError: name
>   'addFavoriteDirectory' is not defined

AND

```
url = "U:\Tyres"
qgis.gui.QgsBrowserDockWidget(addFavorite, uri)
```

...

> Traceback (most recent call last):   File
>   "C:\OSGEO4~1\apps\Python37\lib\code.py", line 90, in runcode
>       exec(code, self.locals)   File "", line 1, in    File "", line 3, in  NameError: name 'addFavorite' is
>   not defined

Should I be calling the addFavorite code differently? This is within the Python console and script area of same.

Comment: A bit unclear from the documentation, there's a way to do this using a File Explorer:

iface.mainWindow().findChild(QDockWidget, 'Browser').addFavoriteDirectory()

But passing in a URI as an argument I believe must be done through the QgsBrowserModel, as they mention here: https://qgis.org/pyqgis/master/gui/QgsBrowserDockWidget.html#qgis.gui.QgsBrowserDockWidget.addFavoriteDirectory

Comment: Thanks - that does work, but doesn't get me to the quick way of applying a set of folders, as each would have to be manually added.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

To know about startup.py, look at https://docs.qgis.org/testing/en/docs/pyqgis_developer_cookbook/intro.html#run-python-code-when-qgis-starts

Now, you know more, to load automatically at each startup, in `startup.py`, do

```py
from qgis.utils import iface

browserModel = iface.browserModel()
dirs = ['U:\dir1', 'U:\dir2', 'U:\dir3', 'U:\dir4']
for dir in dirs:
    browserModel.addFavoriteDirectory(dir)

browserModel.reload()
```

If you are not happy with default `startup.py` path due to restrictions on each computer, you may configure in `QGIS.bat` file the environment variable `PYQGIS_STARTUP`.

You could set it to `PYQGIS_STARTUP=%UserProfile%\startup.py` and you will just need to copy your `startup.py` file in `C:\Users\<username>` (see https://www.tenforums.com/tutorials/3234-environment-variables-windows-10-a.html to understand where `%UserProfile%` is coming from)

Comment: Brilliant, thank you! That works a treat as the code itself within QGIS and I will explore the startup.py in the environment too.

Comment: Can you accept the answer?

Comment: Yes, done now - apologies, had missed that.